# exact match result in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastisearch indices mapping for keyword is

```
"keywords": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

and the values are stored in the comma separator format.

**Eg: "keywords": "Coffee table, teakwood table, teapoy"**

in the query, if am searching for **Coffee** or the **table** it should not show this result. if am searching for **Coffee table** or **teakwood table** or **teapoy** then only this result should show.

Query which am using:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "coffee",
                        "fields": [
                            "keywords^2",
                            "title^1"
                        ],
                        "type": "best_fields",
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to search against `keywords.keyword` field, not `keywords`. As per your mapping `keywords` has type `text` while `keywords.keyword` is `keyword` and this is what you are looking for:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Coffee table",

                        "fields": [
                            "keywords.keyword^2",
                            "title^1"
                        ],
                        "type": "best_fields",
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note that search against `keyword` type is case-sensitive.

Comment: if am searching for  **"query": "table",** coffee table result is showing when am entering the query **Coffee table** then only the result should show

Comment: "Coffee table" won't show up if you query "table" against "keywords.keyword", that is not how "keyword" type works.

Comment: **"query": "Coffee table"** using this, result is not showing